# How does my professor go from this logarithm to the following one of a different base?

Tags: proof-writing, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

[image]

I don't understand on the second last line how my professor goes from $2^{log_3(n)} = n^{log_3(2)}$ how is that relation formed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\log_b a = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$, so

$$2^{\log_3 n} = 2^{\frac{\log n}{\log 3}} = \exp\left(\log 2 \cdot \frac{\log n}{\log 3}\right) = \exp \left(\log n \cdot\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}\right) = n^{\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}} = n^{\log_3 2}.$$

Comment: For that first identity, what base are the numerator and denominator? 10?

Comment: And also, what does exp() mean?

Comment: As a mathematician, unless a base is explicitly specified, I use base $e$. But the cool thing is, _it doesn't matter_ for that identity. It holds in all bases.

Comment: And $\exp()$ is the exponential function, $\exp(z) = e^z$. It's just nicer for readability sometimes to write it $\exp$.

Comment: If we wished, we could in the above use base $23$ for the logarithm and exponential function, and it would not change one iota.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. But I'm having trouble grasping what you did from $2^{log(n)/log(3)}$ to the next step with the exp.

Comment: $x = \exp(\log x)$, and $\log (y^c) = c\cdot \log y$ (again base-independent, as long as $\log$ and $\exp$ use the same base). So $2^y = \exp (y\cdot \log 2)$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10978/discussion-between-doug-smith-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the base-three logarithm of them both. Apply known logarithm properties.

Answer (score 1):

Change of basis property of logarithms:

$$\log_3n=\frac{\log_2n}{\log_23}\implies 2^{\log_3n}=\left(2^{\log_2n}\right)^{1/\log_23}=n^{1/\log_23}=n^{\log_32}$$